# How do change\control mouse position in UWP when the application window is not focused?

Tags: c#, windows, pointers, uwp, mouse

So basically i want to change the mouse location when my UWP app is minimized (or not focused).

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

***this is for windows forms.***

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition = new Point(500, 500);
```

***This method is for uwp app but will only work with in the current UWP application, not outside.***

I want to move cursor outside of my current window.

Comment: Probably not a solution to your real problem, but you are looking for `SetCursorPos`.

Comment: Anyway, I rolled back your edit. You cannot substantially change your question after someone submitted an answer.

Comment: Does `SetCursorPos` method not work? Do you control the window to be minimized in the button click event? Could you please provide your test code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SetCursorPos func from user32.dll:

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

Add System.Runtime.InteropServices name at the top of your file

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Example:

```
SetCursorPos(500, 500);
```

Comment: This will not work when the application is not focused.

Comment: You said: "SetCursorPos will always work as advertised", my question clearly states: "When the application window is not focused". So this method won't work when my app is not focused.